# MYSQL Access denied ruby script in Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04

I have a Rails 4.2 application deployed to an Ubunutu 14.4 Trusty server. The issue I'm having right now is being unable to run a script that saves records for me. I get this error:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I've configured the production database to use username root with the right password, yet after restarting the server and trying out the new configuration I get the above error.

I'm running to script by navigating to lib/ on the server and running `ruby script9000.rb`. The script runs fine until it tries to save a record.

Why might this be happening?

---

The script trips up at `Year.find_or_create_by`

```
  def save_record(record)
    sanitize_record(record)
    full_year = complete_year(@@record["year_number"])
    if full_year >= 2014
      year = Year.find_or_create_by(year: full_year)
      year.records.create(@@record)
    end
  end
```

Comment: without seeing the script there's not much to do besides blindly guess

Comment: I added the part where it breaks. The actual script is huge. This was working on another server I had. My guess is that it has something to do with the way MYSQL is set up.

Comment: Looks like a MySQL credentials concern. Where does your app specify user & login? Perhaps this would be a good opportunity to setup a new MySQL user with stricter privs, rather than using root?

Comment: It specifies this inside the database.local.yml file. I can create a new database user. Maybe that's the problem actually, though I'm not sure. I'll try now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It is MySQL error, that means that you are trying to connect to database with the user **root** from **localhost** with blank or no password.
Make sure, you have user root@localhost on your mysql server or make sure to provide right password.

Comment: I removed the password from root's mysql account. It was able to save. However this is very insecure and I need to fix that. What exactly is using the root user without a password? That very thing that that's running, it seems I have to configure it to run with a password? And why is the script running as root when I am running the script myself with my deploy user?

Comment: Script can be executed as any user. More important, what user and password are used, when your script connects to database and how are you connecting.

Answer (score 1):

It could be coming from several issues as you describe your workflow.

From the small context: run your script with `RAILS_ENV=production ruby script9000.rb`